# Confusing with "&&" and "||"

Tags: java, c++

What are the difference between case 1 and other two cases?
Case 1 : `false && false || true`
Case 2 : `(false && false) || true`
Case 3 : `false && ( false || true )`

Comment: Read a good C++ programming book. Then read a good Java programming book. Java and C++ are different programming languages.

Comment: See this [C++ operator precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: And [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot...
I know C++ and Java are different, but I am not sure whether there is difference in operators.

Answer (score 8):

`&&` has higher precedence than `||`, so case 1 is equivalent to case 2.

See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

---

Actually, case 1 and case 2 are equivalent *expressions*, but there can be a situation where the expression tree itself is different, like here:

```
true ==  false && false  || true  // A
true == (false && false) || true  // B
// not the same!
```

Here they read as:

```
((true ==  false) && false)  || true  // A
 (true == (false  && false)) || true  // B
```

because `==` has an even higher priority than `&&`.

Comment: "&& has higher precedence than ||" - [Same for Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Answer (score 1):

`&&` is noted by `*` in [boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra), and `||` is noted by `+`. read it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128504/boolean-algebra-operation-precedence).

The C/C++ operator precedence is derived usually from the mathematical precedences.

Comment: "The C/C++ operator precedence is derived usually from the mathematical precedences." - Do you have any reference for this? Or at least proof that these specific operators have the same precedence as the respective operators have in mathematical notation? I know one of the other answers already linked to proof of precedence, but this answer, as it stands, is largely speculative. It also doesn't actually answer the question (whether or not the contained links do is largely irrelevant) - just from reading it, I have no idea what the precedence is supposed to be.

Comment: That is how it works in the transistors level:
 
`As with any other branch of mathematics, these operators have an order of precedence. NOT operations have the highest precedence, followed by AND operations, followed by OR operations. Brackets can be used as with other forms of algebra. e.g.

X.Y + Z and X.(Y + Z) are not the same function.` http://www.asic-world.com/digital/boolean1.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Case 1 : false && false || true => true
Case 2 : (false && false) || true => true
Case 3 : false && ( false || true ) => false
```

operation in brackets should always be executed before other operations.

```
case 2 : (false && false) || true => false || true => true

case 3 : false && ( false || true ) => false && true => false

case 1 : false && false || true => false || true => true
```

Answer (score 0):

For case 3, short circuit evaluation causes the expression in the parenthesis after && to be ignored.

[Short-circuit_evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)